# Uploading files and folders to Dropbox

Tags: windows-7, dropbox

Since I've just got [access to an unlimited Dropbox account](https://newsoffice.mit.edu/2014/ist-offers-dropbox-business-file-storage-sharing-mit-community-0821), I am looking for a desktop program that can upload files and folders to a Dropbox account.

If possible:

- free
- Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate
- GUI

I don't want to have to copy the files/folders to the dedicated Dropbox folder as I need to when using the [Dropbox official program](https://www.dropbox.com/install).

Also, I don't want to have to synchronize those files/folders, I am aware that [there exist some tools for this purpose](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/sync-other-folders):

> - [Dropbox Folder Sync](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/dropbox-addons/dropbox-folder-sync): Sync or Unsync a folder by just selecting an option from the right click popup/context menu. This is the
>     recommended method.
> - [Dropboxifier](http://dropboxifier.codeplex.com/): An application to help you create and manage Dropbox links across multiple machines. Requires Windows Vista or
>     higher and .NET 4.0.
> - [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html): There is a tutorial on how to use Link Shell Extension in conjunction with Dropbox.
> - [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52&DisplayLang=en): Makes an always-up-to-date copy of one folder with a folder in your Dropbox. This keeps 2 copies of the folder on your
>     computer.
> - [SyncToCloud](http://www.synctocloud.net/): SyncToCloud is the delivery of free software designed to synchronize data from various sources into a cloud,
>     whereby data may be shared based on end-user-defined rules.

or simply using [symbolic links](http://lifehacker.com/5154698/sync-files-and-folders-outside-your-my-dropbox-folder).

Answer (score 3):

The best and only solution I have found so far is [Dropbox Uploader](http://www.andreafabrizi.it/?dropbox_uploader) ([code](https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader), written in shell script, GNU GPL v3), but it is not natively for Windows (needs Cygwin) and is CLI:

To list all contents in the top-level directory:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh list
```

To list all contents in a specific folder:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh list Documents/manuals
```

To upload a local file to a remote Dropbox folder:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh upload snort.pdf Documents/manuals
```

To download a remote file from Dropbox to a local file:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh download Documents/manuals/mysql.pdf ./mysql.pdf
```

To download an entire remote folder from Dropbox to a local folder:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh download Documents/manuals ./manuals
```

To create a new remote folder on Dropbox:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh mkdir Documents/whitepapers
```

To delete an entire remote folder (including all its contents) on Dropbox:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh delete Documents/manuals
```

It works with MacOSX, Windows/Cygwin, and Unix.

Other nice features:

- File and recursive directory download
- File and recursive directory upload
- Support for the official Dropbox API
- No password required or stored

Main drawback:

- cannot resume upload in case it gets stopped

Example: recursive upload:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Boxifier](http://www.boxifier.com) can sync folders to Dropbox without moving them from their location. It works with folders on local drives, USB/external drives and network shares. It has a GUI and very nice explorer integration. You just right click a folder in order to sync it. That's it.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should have make it clearer I don't want to synchronize the folders / files that I want to upload (there indeed exist a bunch of tools for it: http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/sync-other-folders, or simply using symbolic link http://lifehacker.com/5154698/sync-files-and-folders-outside-your-my-dropbox-folder)

Comment: If you only want to upload them, you can use Selective Sync in Dropbox once they are uploaded using Boxifier. By the way, symlinks don't really work and the other tools mentioned there force you to move your folder in the Dropbox folder. You need to restart Dropbox everytime you make a change to the symlinked folder if you want Dropbox to pick up the changes. Boxifier doesn't have any of these limitations.

Comment: Yes, good point, that's indeed [what I do](http://superuser.com/a/802400/116475), but it's a bit tedious. Ideally I'd like to use Dropbox as some FTP server :)

Comment: Nice script. I thought you were looking for something with a GUI/user-friendly, but your script seems to serve your needs just fine.

Comment: Except that it has no resume feature, in case the computer needs to be restarted or dropbox connection fails :( It can skip files that already exist on dropbox, but it takes forever if you have many files. Also, the upload is mono-threaded. Basically it needs to have some wrapper to take care of this to be usable on large folders. But very convenient for small folders!

Comment: I see. In case you work with large folders, maybe you want to give Boxifier a try sometime. Uploads are automatically resumed once you get back online.

Comment: Yes, I'll definitely give a shot!

Comment: I seem to recall you from SU, and well, we have the same rules on self-promotion that SU does. You may want to make your affliation clear *and* post answers outside your product.